# Multiple AND and OR conditons for Filter Expression with DynamoDbMapper

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I would like to create a filter expression with DynamoDbMapper such as `Condition A AND Condition B AND (Condition C OR Condition D OR Condition E)`. Seems like DynamoDbMapper could only accept 1 conditional operator only (either all conditions AND operator / all conditions with OR operator).

Is it possible to achieve this with `DynamoDbMapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible. Here is an example for a scan, though it would also work for a query. This example will find all books that are less than $10 and all CDs that are more that $10.

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withN(10));
eav.put(":val2", new AttributeValue().withS("Book"));
eav.put(":val3", new AttributeValue().withS("CD"));

DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
    .withFilterExpression("Price < :val1 and ProductCategory = :val2 or Price > :val1 and ProductCategory = :val3")
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

List<Book> scanResult = mapper.scan(Book.class, scanExpression);
```

You can verify this by checking out the [Syntax for Condition Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Syntax). Also, here is the relevant javadoc for [DynamoDBQueryExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#withFilterExpression-java.lang.String-) and [DynamoDBScanExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBScanExpression.html#withFilterExpression-java.lang.String-).